# Need more volume with my aviation headset (David Clark OneX). I wear hearing aids

Tags: radio-communications

Does anyone know of a way to get more volume out of my David ClarK ANR aviation headset.  I wear hearing aids and often fly in older airplanes with older radios that are scratch/weak/etc.  I select full volume but still have trouble hearing the communications.  Is there any inline booster or something like that?  Thanks....larry

Comment: Is the volume on the radio unit and if installed, intercom unit, all turned up all the way? There are often multiple sources of volume control on the chain, if all are turned up all the way you can get quite a bit of gain out of the system.

Comment: There are [hearing aids which have a bluetooth](https://www.healthyhearing.com/help/hearing-aids/bluetooth) input. While this is not fixing the cause, but the effects, this could be a lead to follow if the audio system can be streamed using bluetooth.

Comment: Disagree with the on-hold call. Headsets and comm's are a big part of aviation, talking with ATC is an importan part of flying.

Comment: I also disagree, as the use of headsets has been an important aspect of improving flight communications and safety in aviation.

Comment: A suggestion would be to employ a portable intercom, and use it just for the headset where the higher audio level is desired.  The portable intercoms generally have an amplifier which can drive 4 headsets and often gives another 15 to 20 db headroom.  You may have to try a few different intercoms to assure that the one you are interested in has enough gain.  Also, if you had a frequency shaping circuit (have a student who needed one for hearing deficits) you could provide equalization to optimize intelligibility without affecting others who plug into the aircraft intercom/audio. Will post if..

Answer (score 2):

[This is a decent article to take a look at](https://www.sportys.com/pilotshop/pirep/Aviation_Headsets_and_Hearing_Aids/) but you may want [to consider the clarity aloft headsets](https://www.clarityaloft.com/pages/specialized-pilot-headset-uses) which use hearing aid speakers and seem to be able to serve as a nice drop in replacement.

> **I have a hearing loss. Can I use this headset with my hearing aid?**
>
> Because our headset uses high quality hearing aid speakers, the pilots
>   who have hearing impairment just remove their existing hearing aids
>   before putting on our headset. A balance control can be adjusted to
>   favor one ear with louder sound. We have many pilots who have a range
>   of hearing problems from mild to moderate.